# Android ListView getCheckedItem returning null for items out of view

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

I have a ListView which displays upto four items at a time in a view.If the List has more items then it turns automatically into a scrollable list.

Now i have that list's choice mode changed to single:
`lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);`

So user can select a single item.And after selecting an item user needs to click a button.

Now when the list is upto 4 items everything works fine. As the list gets more items added up, i have  a NullPointerException error at this line :

`String s = ((TextView) lv.getChildAt(p)).getText().toString();`

Here's the full code of the button's OnClick method:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int p =  lv.getCheckedItemPosition();
        if(p>=0){
            String s = ((TextView) lv.getChildAt(p)).getText().toString();
             }
      }
```

Full Stack Trace:

```
03-29 23:00:07.424: E/AndroidRuntime(334): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 23:00:07.424: E/AndroidRuntime(334): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 23:00:07.424: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.username.appname.activityname.onClick(ActivityName.java:48)
03-29 23:00:07.424: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
03-29 23:00:07.424: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
03-29 23:00:07.424: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-29 23:00:07.424: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-29 23:00:07.424: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-29 23:00:07.424: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-29 23:00:07.424: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 23:00:07.424: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-29 23:00:07.424: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-29 23:00:07.424: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-29 23:00:07.424: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: When you populate listview you pass data to adapter from listview class. So you have that data in your listiview class you can get value from that data by mapping getselecteditem value to that data array.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an onitemclicklistener for the ListView, and when the item is clicked. Store that item as a String and then call that when button pressed?